# Calling a function from within a callback causes node app to hang

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have updated the post with the actual code.

The problem is that the node app hangs and does not exit unless I comment out the query in addArticle. I am wonder what I'm doing wrong here (in regards to the hanging problem).

```
function addArticle(title, text, date, link) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE link LIKE "+connection.escape(link), function(error, rows, fields) {
    if(rows.length == 0) {
      console.log("article not in database");
      console.log(connection.escape(title));
      var values = [connection.escape(title), connection.escape(text), date, connection.escape(link), '{}'];
      connection.query("INSERT INTO articles (title, text, date, link, topics) VALUES ?", [[values]], function(err) {
        if(err) throw err; 
      });
    }
  });
}

function scrapeReuters() {
  var url = 'http://www.reuters.com/news/archive/technologyNews?date=10092013';
  request(url, function(err, resp, body){
      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      links = $('a');
      $(links).each(function(i, link){
        var addr = $(link).attr('href');
        if(addr != undefined && addr.indexOf('article') != -1 && addr.indexOf('http') == -1 ) { 
          var full_link = "http://www.reuters.com"+addr;
          var title = $(link).text();  
          request(full_link, function(err, resp, body){
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            para = $('p').text();
            addArticle(title, para,new Date().getTime(), full_link);
          }); 
        }   
      }); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: What is `foo`? Can you do some `console.log`ging to see where your control flows to?

Comment: Is `c` a callback function in `foo`? If so, you need to invoke `c()` in the callback to `connection.query`. You'd need to provide less cryptic function/parameter names for a more helpful comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to close the connection after all the queries have finished. You can try using the https://github.com/caolan/async library to run the queries in sequence and then in a master callback, close the connection.

Its a little tricky, but first you need to define an array of functions to execute. Then you run async.sequence(arrayOfFns,masterCallback). The master callback gets errs and results (notice plural, its from all the functions). In that master callback, terminate the mysql connection/and or end the process.

To do this, I would rewrite the addArticle query to just return the query string. Then before your `$(links).each` loop, I would make an array called `toInsert`

In each loop I would say

```
toInsert.push(function(callback) {
    connection.query(addArticle(...),function(err) {
         if(err) callback(err);
         else callback(null,true);
    });
});
```

Then after the loop run

```
 async.sequence(toInsert,function(errs,results) {
      connection.close() //not sure if correct
      process.exit(); //maybe, if needed?
 });
```

Comment: Closing the connection was indeed what I needed to do. Interestingly, assigning the connection var outside of any functions was causing the connection.end() call to throw an exception. Moving that code into the function that does the actual db interaction fixed that.